# Specifying the file that triggers to event in Lambda code

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

**issue:** I am unable to specify the file that triggers the event.  The goal is to add a watermark to uploaded video files.  I have successfully done this within elastic transcoder by creating a pipeline and job, but the goal is to now automate this process once files are uploaded.

I now want to automate this process on file uploads to the s3 bucket.

**This is my attempt (will explain my issue after code):**

```
require 'json'
require 'aws-sdk-elastictranscoder'
require "aws-sdk-s3"


def lambda_handler(event:, context:)
  client = Aws::ElasticTranscoder::Client.new(region: 'us-east-1')

  s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new()
  # object = s3.bucket(bucket_name).object(object_name)
  # bucket_name = event["s3"]["bucket"]["name"]
  # object_name = event["s3"]["object"]["key"]

    resp = client.create_job({
  pipeline_id: "1552343938210-qevnz1", # required
  input: {
    key: "#{s3}",
    },
  output: {
    key: "#{s3}",
   preset_id: "1351620000001-000001",
    watermarks: [
      {
        preset_watermark_id: "TopRight",
        input_key: "uploads/listing/image/10/listing_howard-stern.jpg",
       },
    ],
  }
  })

end
```

see, where:

```
key: "#{s3}",
    },
```

This is where i have issues.  I am unsure on how to call the exact file that is triggering the event.  I want to file that is being uploaded to have a watermark added to it, and then output'ed into the same file name in same location.

**this gives me back:**

`input=#<Aws::S3::Resource:0x000055bc11bb4388>\` and nothing happens, the job fails due to the input not being specified.

How can i define or specify the file?

I cannot find a way so far.

Comment: Why do you create S3 resource inside the lambda if the goal is to process already uploaded stuff? As far as I understood, the lambda itself is triggered by the uploaded file, right? In this case, you should use S3 event payload which contains the name of the file (see here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3.html)

Comment: Hm, so you're saying, even if I could specify the file, I couldn't even change it because it's not in the s3 bucket yet since the lambda is ahead of that?